# Converter um arquivo XML em BSON

Tags: c#, xml, mongodb-csharp

Tenho um Xml Complexo que contém nós "filhos" e preciso convertê-lo em `BSON`. Estou utilizando VS 2013 (C#).

Comment: O titulo diz BSON, mas a questao fala em JSON...

Comment: A questão original foi editada mudando de BSON para JSON pelo Marconi. Eu sugeri que o título fosse editado para JSON, antes de ver que a questão tinha sido editada. Acredito que a dúvida original se refira a BSON mesmo.

Comment: Pessoal realmente minha necessidade é de Xml para Bson! Por tratar de um xml complexo(muitos nós filhos) comecei com duas classes que transformam xml em ExpandoObject e outra que faz o caminho inverso ExpandoObject para Xml. Estou agora a pesquisar com transformar de ExpandoObject para Bson e vice-versa.

Comment: @LuizRocha Poderia conferir se a resposta que forneci atende à sua pergunta? Acho que aqui ficou esquecido.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que seria interessante serializar seu XML em um objeto dinâmico primeiro:

```
public class XmlToDynamic
{
  public static void Parse(dynamic parent, XElement node)
  {
    if (node.HasElements)
    {
      if (node.Elements(node.Elements().First().Name.LocalName).Count() > 1)
      {
        //list
        var item = new ExpandoObject();
        var list = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (var element in node.Elements())
        {            
          Parse(list, element);            
        }

        AddProperty(item, node.Elements().First().Name.LocalName, list);
        AddProperty(parent, node.Name.ToString(), item);
      }
      else
      {
        var item = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (var attribute in node.Attributes())
        {
          AddProperty(item, attribute.Name.ToString(), attribute.Value.Trim());
        }

        //element
        foreach (var element in node.Elements())
        {
          Parse(item, element);
        }

        AddProperty(parent, node.Name.ToString(), item);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      AddProperty(parent, node.Name.ToString(), node.Value.Trim());
    }
  }

  private static void AddProperty(dynamic parent, string name, object value)
  {
    if (parent is List<dynamic>)
    {
      (parent as List<dynamic>).Add(value);
    }
    else
    {
      (parent as IDictionary<String, object>)[name] = value;
    }
  }
}
```

[Tirei o código daqui](http://www.itdevspace.com/2012/07/parse-xml-to-dynamic-object-in-c.html).

Uso:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader("seu_xml.xml")); 
dynamic meuObjetoDinamico = new ExpandoObject();
XmlToDynamic.Parse(meuObjetoDinamico, xDoc.Elements().First());
```

Depois disso, basta usar o método de extensão [que ensinei a fazer nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60644/2999).