# Expando Object para Bson

Tags: c#, mongodb-csharp

Como posso construir um `parse` de Expando `Object` para Bson? (Vs 2013 - C# - MongoDB)

Comment: A pergunta é boa. Não tem qualquer problema com ela.

Comment: Eu fiz pular por não conhecer o assunto, mas parecia-me amplo de mais.

Comment: Votando para reabrir.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez vê se a pergunta está melhor assim.

Comment: É, está um pouco mais objetiva. A pergunta na verdade é muito simples. Escrever mais seria pura prolixidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia, pessoal! Mais uma vez muito obrigado pela ajuda! Acabei [utilizando uma biblioteca externa](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm) muito eficaz.

Obs: Converti no final para `String` só para efetuar alguns testes.

```
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;        

namespace xml
{ 
     class xmlParse
     {
       public static string object_2_Bson(ExpandoObject obj)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(ms))
               {
                 JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                 serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
               }
            string bsonString = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            return bsonString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu Cigano por ajustar o cogigo aqui! kkk

Answer (score 7):

Para este caso, o ideal seria um método de extensão mais ou menos assim:

```
public static class BsonExtensions 
{
    public static BsonDocument ParaBsonDocument(this ExpandoObject obj) 
    {
        var retorno = new BsonDocument();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in obj) 
        {
            retorno[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        }

        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var bsonEsperado = meuExpandoObject.ParaBsonDocument();
```

Comment: Boa tarde Cigano! Estou tendo um pequeno erro na linha abaixo:                                  retorno[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;  Cannot implicity convert type 'object' to 'MongoDB.Bdon.BsonValue'
Alguem ja viu esse erro!?

Comment: Boa solução Cigano muito obrigado não implementei ela exatamente mas utilizei a idéia geral!

Comment: @LuizRocha Gostaria de responder com o resultado da sua implementação? Poderia ajudar outras pessoas que estejam com o mesmo problema.